# Adding a URL parameter to a PHP form

Tags: php, forms, parameters

I have a form in a php page into which I would like to automatically add a URL paramenter into a field. The address would look something like:

http://www.websiteaddress/admin/add_data.php?file_name=image.jpg

The page add_data.php contains the following form (I've removed some colums for brevity). All I want to achieve is that the parameter file_name is the data entered into the cell containing:

```
<input type="text" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $row_getShip['image']; ?>" maxlength="150" />
```

So that when clicking 'insert' the name of the image file is already filled in in the correct box

Please help!

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="1312" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $row_getShip['image']; ?>" maxlength="150" /></td>
      <td><div align="right">
        <input name="hiddenField" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $row_getShip['ship_id']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
        <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Update" />
      </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 <input type="text" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $_GET['file_name']; ?>" maxlength="150" />
```

All values in url can be retrieved using php **$_GET** global variable

eg in your case `$_GET['file_name']` returns image name.

Comment: Thank you for that - can I ask a stupid question..... There are about 10 fields on the full table, and the code for each one is similar to this.... <input name="class" type="text" id="class" value="<?php echo $row_getShip['class']; ?>" maxlength="150" /> Would I just replace this whole line with the one you suggested or integrate in some way? Thank you

Comment: You can save whole tag in a variable and echo that variable ,

Comment: Like 
  <?php 
  $image= "<input type='text' name='image' id='image'   
value="$_GET['file_name']" maxlength='150' />";

//wants to use this line here
  
  echo $image;
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

To get that value from the url use:

```
$_GET['file_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You would grab the value using $_GET. You could put this at the top of your script.

```
$row_getShip['image'] = $_GET['filename'];
```